# codeigniter controller: how to add php function? (for strtotime)

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am quite new to all this, so I need a little bit help.

My controller:

```
function show_job_id(){
        $id= $this->input->post('cuid');
        $data = $this->job_model->show_job_id($id); 
        echo json_encode( $data );
    }
```

For testing I do a simple JS alert:

```
alert(data[0].work_date+ ' ' +data[0].work_info);
```

Datatype: JSON 
It gives me the correct date but in a mysql format. 
Now I would like to add `date('d.m.Y', strtotime($data)` but to be honest, I don't know how. 
 
I just want to manipulate `work_date` not `work_info`, hope you can give me an hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update only `work_date` property and then `json_encode` it. Try following:

```
$data = $this->job_model->show_job_id($id); 
$data[0]->work_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($data[0]->work_date));
echo json_encode( $data );
```

Comment: Why move everything through a temporary array. Whatever you do to that you could have done directly to `$data`

Comment: Hmm got this error: `Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '='`

Comment: That one: `$data[0].work_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($data[0].work_date));`

Comment: @fips123 Is `data` is array containing multiple elements?

Comment: You can create in your JS. You have to write simple logic for this.

Answer (score 0):

something like this my be better for looping data :

```
$data = $this->job_model->show_job_id($id); 
foreach($data as $row){
$row->work_date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($row->work_date));
$new_data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode( $new_data);
```